# Implementación de tubería

Tags: c

Muy buenas. Estoy implementando un shell tipo bash en C, y me están surgiendo problemas de ejecución con el manejo de descriptores de fichero. Adjunto la parte del código, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar:

```
        case PIPE:

        pcmd = (struct pipecmd*)cmd;
        if (pipe(p) < 0)
        {
            perror("pipe");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        int fstdout=-1, fstdin=-1;          

        if (pcmd->left->type == EXEC && is_internal(((struct execcmd*) pcmd->left)->argv[0]) != -1){

            // Guardamos la salida estándar
            TRY( fstdout = dup(1) );    

            TRY( close(1) );
            TRY( dup(p[1]) );
            TRY( close(p[1]) ); 

            run_cmd(pcmd->left);


        }else{

            // Ejecución del hijo de la izquierda
            if (fork_or_panic("fork PIPE left") == 0)
            {
                TRY( close(1) );
                TRY( dup(p[1]) );
                TRY( close(p[1]) );
                TRY( close(p[0]) );


                run_cmd(pcmd->left);

                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
        }

        if (pcmd->right->type == EXEC && is_internal(((struct execcmd*) pcmd->right)->argv[0])!= -1)
        {

            // Guardamos la entrada estándar
            TRY( fstdin = dup(0) );

            TRY( close(0) );
            TRY( dup(p[0]) );
            TRY( close(p[0]) );

            run_cmd(pcmd->right) ;


        }else{


            // Ejecución del hijo de la derecha
            if (fork_or_panic("fork PIPE right") == 0)
            {
                TRY( close(0) );
                TRY( dup(p[0]) );
                TRY( close(p[0]) );
                if( fstdout==-1 )
                    TRY( close(p[1]) );

                run_cmd(pcmd->right);

                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
        }

        if(fstdout<0 && fstdin<0){
            TRY( close(p[0]) );
            TRY( close(p[1]) );
            // Esperar a ambos hijos

            TRY( wait(NULL) );
            TRY( wait(NULL) );
        }else{
            // Cerramos las entradas y las salidas y abrimos de nuevo la estándar. Si 
            // solo hay un proceso hijo, solo tendremos que esperar a uno.

            if(fstdin>=0){  
                TRY( close(0) );
                TRY( dup(fstdin) );
                TRY( close(fstdin) );
                TRY( close(p[1]) );
                TRY( wait(NULL) );  
            }
            if(fstdout>=0){
                TRY( close(1) );
                TRY( dup(fstdout) );
                TRY( close(fstdout) );
                TRY( close(p[0]) );
                TRY( wait(NULL) );
            }
        }

        break;
```

El programa se basa en crear hijos por cada comando cmd que se teclea, excepto si son comandos internos. Si el comando no es interno, se crea un hijo con fork y se llama a exec directamente. Si sí es interno, sin embargo, tengo una implementación en el código testeada que funciona.

Los problemas salen a raíz de la casuística de cerrar y abrir descriptores y, por ejemplo, al ejecutar esta línea de comandos:

> cwd | tr / :

Donde cwd es un comando interno similar al pwd de bash, y tr es el tr de bash. En ejecución, se queda colgado en el wait(NULL) del bloque if(fstdout>=0)...